# Filtering function with Dc.Js and Update Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, dc.js

I have this function to refresh my charts with Dc.Js And update the selected features on my leaflet map.

```
  // Called when dc.js is filtered (typically from user click interaction)
            var onFilt = function(chart, filter) {
              updateMap(locations.top(Infinity));
            };
```

So it filter on my bar chart in Dc.Js.

```
 citiesChart.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {  

    //console.log('11111111111');
    //console.log(locations.top(Infinity));                 
      updateMap(locations.top(Infinity));

}); 

      dc.renderAll();

// Called when dc.js is filtered (typically from user click interaction)
var onFilt = function(chart, filter) {
console.log('fffff');
  updateMap(locations.top(Infinity));
};
```

I also have a datable in Jquery that I want to refresh when interacting with the charts. I've tried different things to modify my variable 'var onFilt' but cant get it works.

```
datatable.on("filtered", function (chart, filter) { 

    //console.log('11111111111');
    //console.log(locations.top(Infinity));                 
      updateMap(locations.top(Infinity));

}); 

      dc.renderAll();

    // Called when dc.js is filtered (typically from user click interaction)
    var RefreshTable = function(chart, filter) {
    console.log('fffff');
      updateMap(locations.top(Infinity));


    };        

    });
```

Is there a way to modify my 'var onFilt' so it will update my the datable also?

Comment: I don't understand. A datatable usually doesn't filter anything; it responds to filters. So you would want to listen to any filters on the other charts and then update the datatable, no?

Comment: Hi Gordon, Yes your right! So yes i need to update table in function of the filter selected.